# How to handle the return value of the odbc:start(). function in erlang?

Tags: erlang, odbc

I am new to Erlang ,
I am trying to odbc program in erlang

Step 1:- Start odbc 

Step 2:- if odbc is started (i.e) odbc:connect().
         else do nothing

 
odbc:start(). returns two types of value ,

if first time connecting returns {ok}

if its already connected then it return {error, {already_started,odbc}}

How to handle this two types of return values,

How to write the below program

```
-module(test). 
-export([init/0])
init()->
    return_value = odbc:start(),
    if 
        return_value  == {ok} ->
            {ok1, Ref1} = odbc:connect("DSN=mysqlserver;UID=test;PWD=test", []),
        return_value  == {error, {already_started,odbc}}->
           do_nothing
        true ->
           return {error,something_wrong}
    end.
```

Comment: I have used case statement to handle this error ,this is right way?

Answer (score 1):

I have used case statement to handle return.

```
-module(test). 

-export([init/0]).

init()->
    case odbc:start()  of 
        ok ->
            io:fwrite("Started ~n");
        {error,{already_started,odbc}} ->
            io:fwrite("Already Connceted ~n")
    end.
```

In terminal

```
2> c(test).
{ok,test}
3> test:init().
Started 
ok
4> test:init().
Already Connceted 
ok
```

this is correct way?

Comment: Also you may use function ensure_all_started/1,2 -- here is the doc http://erlang.org/doc/apps/kernel/application.html#ensure_all_started-1